# Add 3D model in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, three.js, frontend

I want to add a 3D avatar in my portfolio built with React. I followed this tutorial: [React portfolio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G-Cr00UYokU)

In my header section, I want to replace my image with 3D avatar using three.js following [this tutorial](https://dev.to/nourdinedev/how-to-use-threejs-and-react-to-render-a-3d-model-of-your-self-4kkf)

Here is the Model.jsx file

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import { Canvas, extend, useThree, useFrame } from "react-three-fiber";
import { OrbitControls } from "three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls";

extend({ OrbitControls });
function Model() {
  const Controls = () => {
    const controls = useRef();

    const { camera, gl } = useThree();

    useFrame(() => {
      controls.current.update();
    });

    return (
      <orbitControls
        ref={controls}
        autoRotate
        args={[camera, gl.domElement]}
      ></orbitControls>
    );
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Canvas>
        <mesh>
          <Controls />

          <boxBufferGeometry
            attach="geometry"
            args={[1, 1, 1]}
          ></boxBufferGeometry>

          <meshBasicMaterial
            wireframe
            attach="material"
            color="white"
          ></meshBasicMaterial>
        </mesh>
      </Canvas>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Model;
```

Here is my Header.jsx file

```
import React from 'react'
import './header.css'
import CTA from './CTA'
// import Me from '../../assets/me.jpg'
import HeaderSocials from './HeaderSocials'
import Model from './Model'


const Header = () => {
  return (
    <header id='header'>
      <div className="container header_container">
        <h5>
          Hello I'm
        </h5>
        <h1>John Smith</h1>
        <h5 className="text-light"> Full-stack Developer</h5>
        <CTA />
        <HeaderSocials />
          {/* <div className="me">
          <img src={Me} alt="" />
        </div> */}
        <Model />
        <a href="#contact" className="scroll_down">Scroll Down</a>
     </div>
    </header>
  )
}

export default Header
```

I'm getting this error message:

```
Failed to compile.

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-three-fiber' in 'C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\Projects\react-portfolio\src\components\header'
ERROR in ./src/components/header/Model.jsx 5:0-71
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-three-fiber' in 'C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\Projects\react-portfolio\src\components\header'

webpack compiled with 1 error
```

Can anyone guide me on how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`react-three-fiber` is deprecated, you want to use `@react-three/fiber` instead and so you'd do `npm install @react-three/fiber` or `yarn install @react-three/fiber`. Then you'd have to update your imports like:

```js
import { Canvas, extend, useThree, useFrame } from "@react-three/fiber";
```

Furthermore, if you want to use OrbitControls, the `@react-three/drei` package has them built in as a JSX element, simply import it and do `<OrbitControls />`, more information in their [GitHub page.](https://github.com/pmndrs/drei)

One last advice is that you should wrap your Model inside a `<Suspense>` tag, this is new in React 18 so make sure your `react` and `react-dom` packages are up to date and in-sync.

Comment: I'm new to the wonderful world of three.js, @react-three/fiber, so please bear with me... After some effort, I managed to get some xxxControls working from *three-stdlib*. Should I instead install *drei* and import xxxControls from there ?

Comment: @CapelliC absolutely. Not only is this easier for you but it will make your application much more performant since drei's controls trigger frames manually. More on this here: https://docs.pmnd.rs/react-three-fiber/advanced/scaling-performance

Comment: Thank you! Indeed now I'm using *drei*.

Comment: May I ask if you know how I could get the drei' examples source code from Storybook ?

Comment: Never mind, I found the Story tab hidden at the right border.